# IS the output of binary java serialization is equals to c# serialization

Tags: c#, java

I am working on a project which is made up on c# and there are some of data are serialized And now I need the same values to be serialized in java.

So, can I get the java serialized out put which should equivalent to the c# serialized out put. Because c# code is already been done I cant change the reader format. I need to send the same data by java which is currently in c#.

So, is the serialized out put of both the language are same.

Comment: They are the same in the sense they serve the same purpose. Like you can put out a fire with water or CO2, but they not interchangeable and there is no simple way they could be. Even a stream with no objects would be incompatible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So, is the serialized out put of both the language are same.

Certainly not if you use the default binary serialization mechanisms of each platform. It would be almost inconceivable that they *could* be compatible.

You should pick a platform-neutral serialization format, such as [Protocol Buffers](http://protobuf.googlecode.com), [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/), [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/), JSON, XML (with custom serializers) etc.

Comment: So, can I get the java serialized out put which should equivalent to the c# serialized out put. Because c# code is already been done I cant change the reader format. I need to send the same data by java which is currently in c#.

Comment: @SudikMaharana: You're stuffed, basically. You'd have to reverse engineer the .NET serialization format, which would be horrendously nasty. Bit the bullet and fix it properly.

Comment: reader server now reads the c# format and I need to pass same valu by using java. is it possible by using the above tools.

Comment: @SudikMaharana: No. You've fundamentally got a broken design. Don't try to work around it. Fix it.

Answer (score 4):

The binary serialization is almost always not the same, because of different serialization implementations. However thats why we have XML or Json and other inter-compatible formats, so we can use them regardless of the technology we use.